# How to Remove specific attributes in XMLDocument?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, xattribute

In my C# codebase, I have a `XMLDocument` of the form:

```
<A>
<B>
<C mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> Hi </C>
<D mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> How </D>
<E mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> Are </E>
<F mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> You </F>
</B>
<B>
<C mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> I </C>
<D mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> am</D>
<E mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> fine</E>
<F mlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> thanks</F>
</B>
</A>
```

Using Linq-to-XML or otherwise, I want to remove the `mlns` and `yz` attributes for all the elements contained by element `B`.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML...

```
public static void RemoveAttributes(XNode parent, XName attribute)
{
    // I'm not sure what would happen if we tried to remove the attribute
    // while querying... seems like a bad idea.
    var list = parent.Descendants()
                     .Attributes(attribute)
                     .ToList();

    foreach (var attribute in list)
    {
        attribute.Remove();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
RemoveAttributes(doc, "mlns");
RemoveAttributes(doc, "yz");
```

EDIT: I've just noticed that it should be even easier, in fact, using the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343722.aspx) extension method:

```
public static void RemoveAttributes(XNode parent, XName attribute)
{
    parent.Descendants()
          .Attributes(attribute)
          .Remove();

}
```

So you could even do it without the method pretty simply:

```
doc.Descendants().Attributes("mlns").Remove();
doc.Descendants().Attributes("yz").Remove();
```

Comment: This works for all attributes except for - xmlns - in which case it still not getting removed. I am going topost that as a separate questions.

Comment: @GilliVilla: Yes, `xmlns` is somewhat special in some ways, although I'd still expect it to work... I'll have a look at your new question tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have only these two attributes,

```
 doc.Element("A").Elements("B").Attributes().Remove();
```