# How to remove xmlns attribute from XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

In my C# codebase, I have an `XDocument` of the form:

```xml
<A>
 <B>
   <C xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> Hi </C>
   <D xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> How </D>
   <E xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> Are </E>
   <F xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> You </F>
 </B>
 <B>
   <C xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> I </C>
   <D xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> am</D>
   <E xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> fine</E>
    <F xmlns='blabla' yz='blablaaa'> thanks</F>
 </B>
```

Using Linq-to-XML or otherwise, I wanted to remove the `xmlns` for all the elements contained by element B.

Using the methodology given here: [How to Remove specific attributes in XMLDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997000/how-to-remove-specific-attributes-in-xmldocument), I was able to remove all attributes **except** `xmlns`

What is the best way to remove 'xmlns' attribute from `XDocument`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c)

Comment: Why do you want to? Those aren't normal attributes. They define the namespace.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. And the accepted answer is much cleaner than what is claimed by the 'possible' duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems the namespace information are kept in two places in the object tree that represents the XML document in LINQ to XML: as actual `xmlns` attributes and inside the elements' `Name`s. If you remove it from both places it's gone:

```
doc.Descendants()
   .Attributes()
   .Where( x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration )
   .Remove();

foreach (var elem in doc.Descendants())
    elem.Name = elem.Name.LocalName;
```

(The first part of the code above is copied from now deleted answer by Bertrand Marron.)

If you wanted to remove namespaces from attributes too, that's little more complicated, because their `Name` is read-only:

```
foreach (var attr in doc.Descendants().Attributes())
{
    var elem = attr.Parent;
    attr.Remove();
    elem.Add(new XAttribute(attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value));
}
```

Comment: So actually the `XmlDocument` class does not have a member `.Descendants()`. My guess is that this code is for `XDocument` class which is not what is asked by OP.

Comment: @supertopi The question explicitly asked for LINQ to XML, which is what this answer uses. But yes, that means it's `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Ok, the title is a little misleading :) I will propose a modification

Comment: You can type cast xmlDocument to xDocument easily to apply LINQ

Comment: public static class DocumentExtensions
    {
        public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
        {
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            using(var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
            {
                xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
            }
            return xmlDocument;
        }
     
    }